# Java - Remove only the first backslash

Tags: java

Small Java question regarding how to remove only the first backslash please.

I have a string which looks like this:

```
String s = "\\u6df1\\u5733";
```

Please note, there are two backslashes, and multiple occurrences.

Hence, when this is displayed, the visual result is:

```
\深\圳
```

I would like to just remove any extra backslashes, having a result like this:

```
深圳
```

So far, I have tried this:

```
String s = "\\u6df1\\u5733";
String ss = s.replaceAll("\\", "");
```

But it is still not working.

What is the correct solution please in order to get `深圳` from `"\\u6df1\\u5733"` please?

Thank you

Comment: You tried to use unicode escapes with escaped backslash characters? I'm not sure if its just a copy-paste bug, but you could try using "\u6df1\u5733" (note the single backslash)

Comment: `s.replaceall("\\\\", "");` does this work ?

Comment: In the string literal `"\\u6df1\\u5733"`, each ``\\`` represents *one* backslash. Do you actually have ``\`` in your string, or ``\\``? Or do you have ``\\\u6f1``, which is *one* backslash followed by a unicode character?

Comment: If you just want to remove the backslashes, and leave the unicode characters as they are, that would be `s.replace("\\", "")`. You don't want to use `replaceAll` unless you're using regular expressions.

Comment: Many thanks @khelwood for the comment. Your solution removed the two backslashes. leaving just the alphanumeric. I just want the first backslash of the two to be removed please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
String s = "\\u6df1\\u5733";
Pattern UNICODE_ESCAPE = Pattern.compile("\\\\u[0-9a-f]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String ss = UNICODE_ESCAPE.matcher(s).results()
    .map(x -> new String(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(x.group().substring(2), 16))))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(ss);
```

`UNICODE_ESCAPE.matcher(s).results()` returns the stream of `MatcherResult`.
`x.group().substring(2)` extracts hexadecimal part `"xxxx"` from `"\\uxxxx"`.
`Integer.parseInt(..., 16)` converts it to an integer value that is a code point.
`Caracter.toChars()` converts it to an array of `char`.
`new String(...)` converts it to an `String`.  And `.collect(Collectors.joining())` concatenates the all of them.

output:

```
深圳
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It is working now, thanks

Comment: May I ask if you can explain it a bit what is it please? Especially the

Comment: PAT.matcher(s).results()
    .map(x -> new String(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(x.group().substring(2), 16))))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());

Answer (score 1):

Going by this output:

```
\深\圳
```

you actually have two unicode characters each preceded by *one* backslash.

In a Java string literal, that would look like this:

```
String s = "\\\u6df1\\\u5733";
```

If you want to remove the backslashes (`\\`) and leave the unicode character codes (e.g. `\u6df1`), then you just need [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)).

```
String ss = s.replace("\\", "");
```

[`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) won't work for this, because it requires a regular expression as its first argument.

Comment: replaceAll could work but you have to create a regex with an escaped "\", maybe it's "\\\\" or Pattern.quote("\\"); Which is a bit craze when `replace` is what you want.

Comment: @matt Yes you could make it work with `replaceAll`, but it's the wrong tool to use. Replacing a plain string (without using regular expressions) is what `replace` is for.

Comment: Many thanks @khelwood for the Answer. Your solution removed the two backslashes, in my case ALL backslashes. leaving just the alphanumeric. I just want the first backslash of the two to be removed please

Comment: @PatPatPat Then you probably need to clarify your question. Perhaps you could post a [mre].

Comment: Also you believe I have this string literal, but really, I just have TWO backslashes. you have three

Comment: String s = "\\\u6df1\\\u5733";   <- not what I have

Comment: String s = "\\u6df1\\u5733";   <- what I have

Comment: But that string literal `"\\u6df1\\u5733"` would *not* give you the string `\深\圳`. So *something* in your question is missing or incorrect. Apparently I believed the wrong part of your question.